# Can't Find Renderer2 in Angular 4

Tags: angular, renderer

I may be missing something completely but I am trying to use Renderer2 in my project. From what I can see, it requires Angular4, which I have.

However, whenever I try to add it to my project, it comes up as "/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'"

I've tried updating Angular to the latest, as well as deleting my node_modules folder and running npm install but I still get the same error.

Should I be using Renderer instead? Did I just miss some point of the documentation?

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Version of Angular][image: Visual Studio Code only showing Renderer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting your Visual Studio, this happens to me sometimes too

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. All this time, I thought I was losing my mind and missing some documentation. I really appreciate it (and will keep in mind in the future). And with that, I'm calling it a night! Thanks @Wilco-Tubog